# Unable to create production build of electron app

Tags: angularjs, electron, electron-builder

I am new to electron I have found one example for angular 1. It is working fine it run the app;. But I am try to create production build then .exe file is working. I am getting the following exception:

[image]

This is code of example:

https://github.com/jasimea/ElectronAngular

Can any one help or provide a sample example app for starting.

Comment: That error happens when you run the installer?

Comment: Yes, when I have try run the installer file i.e applicaiton.exe file name

Comment: Maybe the reason is that package.json is required in the sources directory..check

Comment: Package.json file is palced at root folder. I have added the git repo in question. I am using the same code as sample